# LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to layout an android page with a header, footer and body.

I'm using a LinearLayout nested in a RelativeLayout. My issue is only the first TextView inside the Linear is appearing. I'm guessing the other 2 controls are behind the text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:text="kernmobile"
    />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Login"
    />

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer">

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="24dp"
      android:text="Login" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="20dp"
      android:text="Username" />

    <EditText
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="20dp"
      />

  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a super common issue. You seem to want a vertical orientation for your `LinearLayout`, but the [default is horizontal](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setOrientation%28int%29). You need to specify it explicitly:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayout's default orientation is Horizontal.  Add `android:orientation="vertical"` and you should see what you want.